# select radio button based on value

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a shopping cart that is generating the radio button list.  Unfortunately the generated list is repeating ID's so I can't use those as selectors.  An example of the radio button generated is

`<input type="radio" name="ShippingMethodID" id="ShippingMethodID9" value="68|Priority Mail Express International|59.22|0.00">`

The only unique thing is the number at the beginning of the value. How can I create a selector based on the number at the beginning of the value?

I've been searching and found how to find something based on the value. But I'll need to hide it as an option

`str.toLowerCase().indexOf("68")`

Comment: If it's repeating the `id`s you have at least one other problem you need to solve (in addition to this one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
var radio = $("input[type=radio][value^=68]").
```

or possibly:

```
var radio = $("input[type=radio][value^=68|]").
```

(Just in case there's one with a value like `689`.)

---

That said:

> Unfortunately the generated list is repeating ID's so I can't use those as selectors.

That needs fixing. [Repeating `id` values is invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: couldn't agree more on the repeating IDs, but not much I can do there.

Comment: How could I remove the text right after the input?
`<input type="radio" name="ShippingMethodID" id="ShippingMethodID9" value="68|Priority Mail Express International|59.22|0.00">
&nbsp;Priority Mail Express International
 $59.22 (USD)`

Comment: @JonHarding: Something like `var next = $("input[type=radio][value^=68|]")[0].nextSibling; next.parentNode.removeChild(next);` That will remove the node immediately following the input element, even if it's a text node (as in your example).

Comment: Is there a way to remove them both at once? There are about 5 different options that I need to remove (all different leading #s).  It would be nice with one swipe to remove the radio button and text

Comment: @JonHarding: No one-liner, but one-liners are overrated. Four lines, though: http://pastie.org/8201258

Comment: seems to only be removing the radio button. Seriously thanks for the support here.

Comment: @JonHarding: If your structure is really as quoted, that code would also remove the following text node: http://jsbin.com/ehahew/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/ehahew/1/edit)).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34729/discussion-between-jon-harding-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: @JonHarding: Probably better just to ask a new question about that.